# Data does not get written to printwriter

Tags: java, sockets

I am actually trying to create a program :

```
public void setUpNetwork(){
    try {
            Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 1101);
            InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            buff = new BufferedReader(read);
            write = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Network Established");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}
```

Here, once the socket connection is established, I'm trying to pass user entered data to the print stream and then printing out the data in the console.

My server class has only this much:

```
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1101);
        Socket socket = server.accept();
```

When I run this (while running, I first run the server and then the ChatSetUp class), nothing gets printed on the console! Is it because the sersock.accept() gives a socket connection which has a different port and the client can't communicate with the server? If so, I need to pass the socket object from server to setUpNetwork() which is in a different class so that I can create an input stream on it. How do I do it?

Edit:

I've modified the whole program a bit more! I'm using Swing to create the GUI wherein when the user enters text in the text field and hits Send, it triggers the listener and that's where I add the text into PrintWriter. The whole code is given below: ....and setUpNetwork() is also part of this class (not included below)

Edit: Included server code in the same program and starting a new thread for server.

```
public class ChatGraphs {

JTextField field;
JTextArea area;
PrintWriter write;
BufferedReader buff;
Socket sock;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChatGraphs grap = new ChatGraphs();
    grap.doIt();
}

private void doIt() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JPanel allPanel = new JPanel();
    allPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(allPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel areaPanel = new JPanel();
    areaPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel alabel = new JLabel("Chats");
    area = new JTextArea(20, 50);
    area.setEditable(false);
    areaPanel.add(alabel);
    areaPanel.add(area);

    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
    textPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel flabel = new JLabel("Enter");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    JButton button = new JButton("Send");
    button.addActionListener(new ButtonListen());
    textPanel.add(flabel);
    textPanel.add(field);
    textPanel.add(button);

    allPanel.add(areaPanel);
    allPanel.add(textPanel);

    ConnectServer con = new ConnectServer();
    Thread t = new Thread(con);
    t.start();

    AddData add = new AddData();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(add);
    t1.start();

    //setUpServer();
    setUpClient();

    frame.setSize(700,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(allPanel);
}

public class ButtonListen implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     
        write.println(field.getText());
        write.flush();
        field.setText("");
        field.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);

    }
}

private void setUpClient(){
    try {
        sock = new Socket("localhost", 1101);
        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        buff = new BufferedReader(read);
        System.out.println("Network Established");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class AddData implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String line="";
        try {
            while((line=buff.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println("Another net");
                area.append(line);
            }
            buff.close();
            write.close();
            sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class ConnectServer implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
        ServerSocket sersock = null;
        Socket sock = null;
        try {
                sersock = new ServerSocket(1101);
                sock = sersock.accept();
                write = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                sersock.close();
                sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

}
```

The exception I get is :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sockets.ChatGraphs$AddData.run(ChatGraphs.java:120) // This line is : while((line=buff.readLine())!=null)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Network Established
```

Comment: You have more problems than that.  The socket, reader and writer you create in `setUpNetwork()` all go out of scope at the end of the `try` block.  They cease to exist by the time `setUpNetwork()` exits.

Comment: "Is it because the sersock.accept() gives a socket connection which has a different port". That's only the _local_ port. That's ok. Can you give us some more code?

Comment: @JimGarrison I've added more code! Please check!

Comment: @Fildor Added more code!

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's just that I dont understand the server side. If it has just the two line of `new ServerSocket`and `accept()` - where does the server read from client and echo (write) to the client?

Comment: @jboi I'm creating a new `PrintWriter` object using the socket connection. But then as I've already mentioned, I'm not sure if the socket is of client or server. How do I get the socket connection from the server to the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do client and server find each other over Sockets?

- The Client needs to know the network address (IP-Address) of the Server and the port number, the server is listening on.
- The Server just needs to know which Port it is listening. If it has more network interfaces with different IP-Addresses you can optionally constrain Servers listening to one of the network interfaces (one IP-Address)

So the code snippet to connect a client to the server is like:

```
Socket socket4Client = new Socket("IP-Address, e.g. 123.45.67.89", PORT_NUMBER);
```

And the code snippet for the server looks like:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
Socket socket4Server = serverSocket.accept(); // Waits for a Client to connect
```

For the server side, you most probably want to start a new Thread for each incoming connection. Check these [Tiny Applications](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Tiny-Application/Chat.htm) for some very simple (just not oversimplified) examples.

**EDIT/Addition:**

About the new issue `NullPointerException` in the line `while(..`.

You get the exception because `buff` is null. And this happens because the Thread `ConnectServer` is started before the method `setUpClient()` is called. You can create the Thread but must call `setUpClient()` before you actually `start()` the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did create a new thread for the server. Please find the new code! The error now is that I get a `NullPointerException` when it tries to access `buff.readline()`

Comment: You mean AddData should be called after setUpClient() right? No NullPointer Exception after this but nothing is seen on the text area.

Comment: I think now you're at the problems mentioned right in the beginning by @JimGarrison and others. The definition of "Success" is sometimes strange ;-) I'm pretty sure, that Server and Client connect now to each other. It's now about exchangeing the data. I recommend one of the follwoing: **Either** use the example in the [Tiny Applications](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Tiny-Application/Chat.htm) and modify it, **or** fill your code with a lot more logging `System.out.println(...)` to understand what happens really.

Answer (score 4):

`PrintWriter` is one of those classes which don't behave well when it comes to buffering and flushing. An easy fix is to use

```
new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
```

to enable auto-flush.

Or you can call `write.flush()` every time data should be sent to the client.

Note that you need to call `flush()` once before closing the `PrintWriter` because it doesn't do that itself (unlike any other I/O class).

Comment: Thanks for the info! But the issue seems to be something else! As jboi has mentioned above, the issue might be the connection between the server and the client

Comment: How do you know it "seems to be something else"?

Comment: From the code above, it's not clear what you do with the socket you get from `server.accept()`. Can you please post the rest of the server code?

Comment: Modified the code again! I'm using the `PrintWriter` object in `ConnectServer` and assigning it to `write`

Comment: I hope that you read the data the client sends to the server somewhere. Creating a socket doesn't do that; you will have to read from the socket that `accept()` returns.